# Indices of elements in a python list of tuples

Tags: python, list, indexing

### Problem

Given 2 lists A and B, I want to get the indices of all elements in List A which are present in List B. Each element is a tuple.

I am using lists of size 40,000 elements or so.

### Sample case

Input:

```
A = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]

B = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

Expected output:

```
[0,1,2]
```

### Attempted solutions

I tried two solutions:

1) using map function

```
m = map(a.index,b)
list(m)
```

2) using list comprehension

```
m = [a.index(item) for item in b if item in a]
```

These methods seem to be taking too much time. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you provide a clear example of input and output?

Comment: This is unclear. Why are you providing `b` at all? If you're only cheking the position in `a`?

Comment: Why there's a `numpy` tag here? Have you tried using Numpy arrays?

Comment: I took intersection of a and b to get common pixels

Comment: I  tried numpy.intersect1d  to get the indices directly. But since the input is list of tuples , its not giving proper result.

Comment: try np.where with np.all and np.sum. `np.where(np.sum([np.all(np.array(a)== i,axis=1) for i in b],axis=0).astype(bool))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I checked np.where(np.sum([np.all(np.array(a)== i,axis=1) for i in b],axis=0).astype(bool)) and it is working properly on small lists, but on large list ,its taking a lot of time

Comment: I got solution for this issue. I converted the list of tuples into proper numpy array by the following step. dt = np.dtype('int,int')   a= np.array(a,dtype =dt) and then  used np.where to get the indices. Now it takes only 0.04 s for 40k plus matching entries. Thank you all

Comment: @Sruthi Shouldn't the expected output be `[0, 1, 2]` in the sample case?

Answer (score 1):

Below would be your best bet. I am using a set (i.e., **set(B)**) as searching for the specific tuple can be done in O(1) Time Complexity.

```
m = [index for index, tuple in enumerate(A) if tuple in set(B)]
```